# How to unit test ViewBag in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, viewbag

During writing unit tests for ASP.NET Core application I realized that the `ViewData` is accessable from `ViewResult` but `ViewBag` is not.

My **`HomeController`:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHeroRepository _heroItems;
    private readonly IQuestRepository _questItems;

    public HomeController(
        IHeroRepository heroItems,
        IQuestRepository questItems)
    {
        _heroItems = heroItems;
        _questItems = questItems;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var recentHeroesVM = await _heroItems.GetRecentHeroesAsync(2);
        ViewBag.QuestSelectList = await _questItems.GetSelectListAsync();
        return View(recentHeroesVM);
    }
}
```

My **testing class:**

```
public class HomeController_Index
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Index_ReturnsAViewResult_WithAListOfRecentHeros()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockHeroRepo = new Mock<IHeroRepository>();
        var mockQuestRepo = new Mock<IQuestRepository>();
        var recentHerosCount = 2;
        mockHeroRepo.Setup
        (
            repo => repo.GetRecentHerosAsync(recentHerosCount))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(GetTestItems())
        );
        var controller = new HomeController(mockHeroRepo.Object, mockQuestRepo.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await controller.Index();

        // Assert
        var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);

        // No definition error below.
        var questSelectListVB = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<SelectList>(
            viewResult.ViewBag.QuestSelectList);
    }

    private IEnumerable<HeroViewModel> GetTestItems()
    {
        var items = new List<HeroViewModel>
        {
            new HeroViewModel
            {
                Name = "First Hero",
            },
            new HeroViewModel
            {
                Name = "Second Hero",
            },
        };
        return items;
    }
}
```

**Question 1:** Why there is no `ViewBag` property in `ViewResult` when in the ASP.NET MVC version of `ViewResult` class there is clearly one ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ViewBag))?

**Question 2:** How I am supposed to test the `ViewBag` when I have no access to it?

Comment: What is type of `viewResult`? Have you tried to specify type explicitly `ViewResult viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);` (and likely get compile time error)  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Question 1:** Still a mystery for me. More like question for Core developers.

**Question 2:**

> "The `ViewBag` property is a wrapper around `ViewData` that provides a dynamic view over that collection. It is not a separate collection." - [ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview)

So it is one object. Since there is no `ViewBag` property in `ViewResult` (a reminder - we are talking here about Core version), access it in `ViewData` dictionary style:

```
var questSelectListVB = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<SelectList>(viewResult.ViewData["QuestSelectList"]);
```